# Getting the value of external environment variable

Tags: environment-variables, scons, include-path

I am not sure if the correct saying is 'external environment variable'. This is a nooby problem but I could not find in the documentation of scons. I am trying to add a path by:

```
env = Environment (CPPPATH = ['${PETSC_DIR}/include'])
```

but scons recognize the value of `${PETSC_DIR}` as blank. I checked the value with `echo` in the shell and it gives the proper value.  How can I make scons to recognize its value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set environment variable in python script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143971/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-python-script)

Answer (score 2):

SCons doesn't import shell variables by default, in order to guarantee repeatable builds by not affecting the build environment with what you may have defined in your terminal/shell.
However, you can decide to import those variables...and it's shown in the answer to #1 of our "most-asked FAQs" at https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions :

```
import os
env = Environment(ENV = os.environ)
```

for importing ALL the things, or

```
path = ['/bin', '/usr/bin', '/path/to/other/compiler/bin']
env = Environment(ENV = {'PATH' : path})
```

for a single variable, like `PATH` in this example. The above code snippets will make all your shell variables (or only PATH) available in the build environment, as defined by the variable `ENV`.
For your user-defined shell variable to get replaced in the CPPPATH definition, it has to exist in the SCons environment itself. You can treat it like a dictionary, so the following should work:

```
import os
env = Environment(ENV = os.environ)
env['PETSC_DIR'] = os.environ.get('PETSC_DIR','default')
env.Append(CPPPATH=["$PETSC_DIR/include"])
```

Comment: Did you mean to have env={'PATH':os.environ('PATH')} ?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer...for picking up the variable during expansion of the CPPPATH, it has to be a member of the build environment itself. I'll correct my answer accordingly.